# Android HttpClient and HTTPS

Tags: android, ssl, https, httpclient, bad-request

I'm new to implementing HTTPS connections in Android.  Essentially, I'm trying to connect to a server using the org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.  I believe, at some point, I'll need to access the application's keystore in order to authorize my client with a private key.  But, for the moment, I'm just trying to connect and see what happens; I keep getting an HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error.

I can't seem to make heads or tails of this despite many examples (none of them seem to work for me).  My code looks like this (the BODY constant is XmlRPC):

```
 private void connect() throws IOException, URISyntaxException{

    HttpPost post     = new HttpPost(new URI(PROD_URL));
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(BODY));
    HttpResponse result = client.execute(post);

    Log.d("MainActivity", result.getStatusLine().toString());

}
```

So, pretty simple.  Let me know if anyone out there has any advice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

This should get you started.  I'm using basically the same, except with `ThreadSafeClientConnManager`.

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 
            SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, params);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I actually tried a similar approach earlier with no luck; same bad request error.

Comment: Then the problem isn't with HTTPS, it's something else.  The code I pasted works for me.

Comment: Just for clarification: it looks like you're using org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory , which is not the same as javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory . Is that correct?

Comment: @synic hi synic if you know anything about how can we validate the keystore with truststore process please let me know.. that could be helpful for me..thanks in advance...

Comment: @Dalbergia yes it is org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory (I had to frown quite some time before realizing).