# File download hanging

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download, httpurlconnection, connection-reset

after extensive searching I was unable to find a solution to solve a file download problem.

The following script is designed to download a csv file from a remote (Hotmail) server via a
 **WebViewClient**.

The login process is done through the their standard website but I would like to capture the downloaded csv file using the following download class and store in a custom location.

It works fine with URLs that directly link to a file for eg, **site.com/file.pdf** but will not work on processed URLs such as **site.com/downloadFile.php?n=xxxx** where it just hangs until the **connection is reset by the remote server**

```
    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute (String result){

     super.onPostExecute(result);

     mProgressDialog.dismiss();
     mProgressDialog = null;
     }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

        try {

            Log.i("File download", "Started from :"+sUrl[0]);

            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            //URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myDir");

            // create the directory if it doesnt exist
            if (!myDir.exists()) myDir.mkdirs();            

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            //Follow redirects so as some sites redirect to the file location
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);        
            connection.setDoOutput(true);           

            connection.connect();

            File outputFile     =   new File(myDir, "hotmail_contacts.csv");

            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int fileLength      = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input   = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());                
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }


            connection.disconnect();
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

            Log.i("File download", "complete");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("File download", "error: " + e.getMessage());

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above AsyncTask is invoked in the **onDownloadStart(....)** method as follows:

```
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long length) {

        Log.i("File download", "URL:" + url 
                + " UserAgent:" + userAgent
                + "ContentDisposition:" + contentDisposition 
                + "Mime:"+ mimeType + "Length:" + Long.toString(length));



        // instantiate it within the onCreate method
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Email_import.this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("File download");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        // start a new download
        DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
        downloadFile.execute(url);

    }// end onCreate
```

All the relevant permissions are in the manifest such as write external storage, internet and read network state.

Am I missing something here?
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at another post listed [here][1]

[1]: [Download a file from webview to a custom folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860484/download-a-file-from-webview-to-a-custom-folder) I've made some adjustment to my code to call the URL as a **HttpPost** request using a **HttpClient** object as shown below and it seems to be working beautifully:

```
                // Create client and set our specific user-agent string
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(sUrl[0]);               
            request.setHeader("User-Agent", sUrl[1]);               

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            Log.i("File download", "Started from :" + sUrl[0]);

            File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myDir");

            // create the directory if it doesnt exist
            if (!myDir.exists())    myDir.mkdirs();

            File outputFile = new File(myDir, "hotmail_contacts.csv");

            InputStream input   = response.getEntity().getContent();
```