# How to download a fileby webView in Android

Tags: android

I want to  download a file by webView in android . But cant  understand how to do that ? The code for webView is as follows . Can you please suggest me what can I do for downloading a file in webView ?

```
 wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainwebview);
        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
     //   ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //     wv.loadUrl("http://www.ebooksdownloadfree.com/");
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        this.wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        this.wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        this.wv.loadUrl("http://www.ziddu.com/download/20520057/MPTOH.pdf.html");
     wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
          Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

After running this code I got the following error as described in picture : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860484/download-a-file-from-webview-to-a-custom-folder) is helpful for you. FOr download Files on webview in android.

**EDIT :-**

Try following code.

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
      startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: I can not understand the code provided in that answer. Can you integrate that code with mine ? It will be quite helpful for me .........

Comment: Yes I have uploaded this file .