# Android and HTTPS with SSL

Tags: android, ssl, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android HttpClient and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603691/android-httpclient-and-https)

I want to write app on Android which will be exchange XML files with HTTP server. I want to use HTTPS and SSL to secure this connection but I'm really rookie with securing things. I was looking for some tutorial on the internet but all I found was confusing. Can someone explain me how can I use HTTPS and SSL to exchange files with HTTP server. Maybe you know some tutorial or book which describe this?

Comment: Everything you need is Apache HttpClient library which is in Android package by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty of links on internet. Look for Apache HttpClient and HTTPS and file transfer.

For example:

[Android HttpClient and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603691/android-httpclient-and-https)

Answer (score 1):

If your webserver is already properly configured to provide the services in HTTPS or SSL, there isn't much to do on Android side, you basically need to use the API's provided by the platform. Check out the docs starting with: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html